# java.sql.SQLException : Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java, jdbc

Can anyone point me in the write direction to solve the error: SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Here is the code i believe the error occurs in

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String query1 = "";
String query2 = "";

int candidateNo = 42;

query1 = "SELECT * FROM Candidates WHERE CandidateNo = "+ candidateNo;
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query1);
//If query can be completed then display name and prompt to continue
if(rs.next()){
    query2 = "SELECT * FROM Achieved WHERE CandidateNo = " + candidateNo;
    ResultSet ts = stmt.executeQuery(query2);
}
```

I have tried using resultset rs = null; to create the variable but the error still occurs

Comment: Which line throws the exception? Where's the stack trace that should accompany this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the `ResultSet` bound to a `Statement` , then while iterating, you are using the exact same `Statement` object to issue a new query and get and iterate over another `ResultSet` .

This won't work as long as you are not done with the processing of the first `ResultSet`, so consider using a distinct `Statement` object for your second query .

Answer (score 1):

In your code you used 2 ResultSet executing the same Statement object (stmt)concurrently. Use different Statement Objects for both queries.